# wrong keyboard on xubuntu connexion

Tags: xfce

Xubuntu 18.04.2

I installed this version a few weeks ago, and I defined 3 users.

First I defined 2 keyboards, French (azerty) and russian (typewriter).

When I try to connect through a password to one of the users, I am obliged to type in qwerty instead of azerty, using the virtual keyboard on the connexion screen.

For the time being I just cancelled the russian keyborad, keeping only the french keyboard. No progress.

It seems using lightdm.

Any ideas?

See on the french-speaking forum https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2045780

Thanks for you replies.

Comment: I really don't know what I did or what happened, but the problem solved itself...:)